# How to get W* form minimize function

Tags: optimization, matrix-equations, least-squares

I need help to solve this equation

$$\min_{W} ||XW-X||_F^2+p_1||W||_1+p_2R(W), W>=0$$
X size dxn (d = number of feature & n = number of data)
Example input: 
X is random matrix 3x5
$$R(W)=Tr(W^TX^TLXW)$$
L = laplacian matrix
Close solution W
$$W=(X^TX+pI)^-1+X^TX$$
Result:
W* (W* is matrix nxn/5x5)

For complete journal : http://www.massey.ac.nz/~rwang/publications/17-TNNLS-Zhang.pdf

Comment: I can't really tell what your question is.  Are you asking for help with understanding a particular part of the paper you've referenced?  Or is this a separate problem for which that paper is a reference?

Comment: I need help to understanding how to get W*